# Android Layout Shows GreyBoxes on preview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

In android studio, any view I add is shown as a grey box instead of the view, this happens on multipile projects even new projects
I doubt that it is code related
I tried rebuilding the app
restarting Andriod studio
restarting my PC

[image]

Comment: As I can see you android studio found some errors in this layout. Can you share list of this errors or share the layout for the screen?

Comment: It is showing grey because your OerlayLayout is not build properly.Please rebuild the project or run the app on a device and check again